# Conservation Genetics - Book recommendations

Tags: evolution, population-dynamics, book-recommendation, population-genetics, conservation-biology

Can you please give me some advice for a book in (evolutionary) [conservation genetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_genetics) that offers an in-depth review of the mathematical formulations used in this field.

I read the book [Evolutionary Conservation Biology (Ferrière and Dieckmann, 2009)](http://www.amazon.fr/Evolutionary-Conservation-Biology-R%C3%A9gis-Ferri%C3%A8re/dp/0521116082/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1406725200&sr=8-3&keywords=evolutionary%20conservation%20biology) and I really liked it. I'm seeking for another book of the same kind that goes further on the part A (Theory of Extinction) and especially on the concern of the importance of population structure and the genetic load. I am also interested in [landscape genetics](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/landscape_genetics).

Comment: It would be more informative to use google scholar and read papers instead of a single book

Comment: A comprehensive book on ecology????

Comment: @caseyrs547 as the subject remains fairly broad I hoped I could find a book rather than articles. Books are often more entertaining than articles. But you might be right. I'll wait to see if anyone suggest me something.

Comment: @WYSIWYG No, I am not looking at a book on ecology. I am interested in genetics extinction (population genetics based explanation for population extinction) and about how the environment shape the genome of populations. Not a book on this extremely broad field which is ecology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This book "[A primer of conservation genetics](http://www.cambridge.org/se/academic/subjects/life-sciences/ecology-and-conservation/primer-conservation-genetics)" would suit quite well I think. In particular chapter five deals with "Genetics and Extinction" and is preceded by a lot of population genetics based theory. A beginner might also combine it with "A primer of ecological genetics" (Hartl & Conner) but you seem to have enough Pop gen knowledge to not need it!

The landscape genetics is perhaps a bit lacking from this book though. Maybe a better and more comprehensive solution, but slightly more advanced, is [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470671459) which does feature some aspects of landscape genetics in chapter 15 along with good population genetics type coverage of extinction.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in learning about the mathematics of population genetics, [Population Genetics and Microevolutionary Theory](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470047356) by Alan Templeton is an absolutely amazing resource.

If you check out the index, here are entries under population structure:
assortative mating, admixture, linkage disequilibrium, coarse-grained spatial heterogeneity, gene flow, gene flow and population history, gene flow vs admixture, microevolution modeling, multiple inheritance modes, natural selection, adaptation, and fitness.

Heterozygosity and other mathematical descriptors are particularly relevant to conservation (the author has been involved in various conservation projects). Furthermore, there are various entries on viability.

Plus there's plenty of information in it about the effects of landscape on gene flow and other population structural features.